# Get dict from Mongo and convert to ndarray using Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, numpy

I have an aggregate query in Mongo that returns data like:

```
{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
{a: 4, b: 5, c: 6}
{a: 7, b: 8, c: 9}
```

I would like to do an FFT for a, b and c and I need to put the data in 3 numpy arrays like this:

```
a = np.array([1, 4, 7])
b = np.array([2, 5, 8])
c = np.array([3, 6, 9])
```

What is the best option to do this using numpy as for now I am doing a for loop and it takes ages.

**UPDATE:**

The result from mongo is a Cursor which is iterable
The way that I am doing it now is like this:

```
a = []
b = []
c = []
for item in aggregation_list:
    a.append(item['a'])
    b.append(item['b'])
    c.append(item['c'])
```

Comment: can you show the logic that you have written for it?

Comment: Also what would you be constructing the array from, a list of dictionaries?

Comment: if the mongo data is in a list of dicts you could turn it into a dataframe and from there vectorise the data in what you need

Comment: @ErikK could you give me an example, please? The mongo data is in a Cursor, which is iterable

Comment: ```df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(aggregation_list)
a = np.array(df['a'])
...
```

Comment: @tatulea did it work?

Comment: Yes, it is working. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the data comes in a format that would be able to go into pandas easily and from the there Pandas API is much faster because you can vectorise instead of looping.

```
aggregation_list = [
    {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
    {a: 4, b: 5, c: 6}
    {a: 7, b: 8, c: 9}
]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(aggregation_list)

a = np.array(df['a'])
b = np.array(df['b'])
c = np.array(df['c'])
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a list of dictionaries from the MongoDB query, here's how you could construct an array from its values:

```
dicts = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6} ,{'a': 7, 'b': 8, 'c': 9}]
```

You could unpack the different rows into different variables like so (altough this requires prior knowledge of the amount of dictionaries, and only makes sense for a few dictionaries):

```
a,b,c = np.array(list(zip(*map(dict.values, dicts))))

print(a)
# [1 4 7]
...
```

A better approach would be to build a ndarray, with each row containing the interleaved values from the above dictionaries's values:

```
np.array(list(zip(*map(dict.values, dicts))))

array([[1, 4, 7],
       [2, 5, 8],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it takes a bit longer than with the for loop approach. Is there any other option I could use?